# Malformed access token facebook ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get place_id from facebook for facebook checkin section.For that i am using following code.While requesting place id with access token sometines i get message as malformed access token,sometimes expired.

```
 NSString *fbToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
 NSString *fbURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ritual&type=place&center=9.952786,76.339828&distance=1000&access_token=%@",fbToken];

 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",fbURL, fbToken]];
NSLog(@"URL:%@",URL);
NSURLRequest *placeRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

//Send the request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:placeRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (!connectionError) {

         NSDictionary *Data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

         NSLog(@"data = %@"Data);


     }

 }];
```